# Plot individual graphs for values of every row from a large data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bokeh

I have a large dataset with more than 20k rows and about 6 columns.

I can very well plot a graph when the values are in columns. But this is a different case.

Input:

```
Title,2016,2015,2014,2013,2012
aaa,45,76,23,765,65
bbb,245,633,35,75,654
ccc,74,74,23,764,864
ddd,34,63,235,63,244
```

I am trying to plot individual bar/line/scatter graph for every row with

graph title: name from column title

x axis: headers years `2016,2015,2014,2013,2012` 
y axis: the values in individual row.

Every row with a new plot file can be automatically saved with title names as file names.

I have tried with bokeh and Seaborn but I am not able to plot one row after another.

Appreciate the help, Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think for your case, using a normal graph instead of bar graph would be better (because of huge data size.)
See if this helps: https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: Why do you need 20,000 small images?